# How to get original DDL from table created in SNWOFLAKE environment?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am attempting to retrieve the original SQL (or DDL) behind 2 tables I created months ago in SNOWFLAKE. Does anyone know the query I would need to retrive this original DDL?

Answer (score 4):

Using [QUERY_HISTORY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/query_history.html) to find the actual query:

```
SELECT qh.QUERY_TEXT, *
FROM SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.QUERY_HISTORY qh
WHERE qh.QUERY_TEXT ILIKE '%CREATE%TABLE%<table_name_here>%';
```

---

Alternatively current definition:

```
SELECT GET_DDL('table', '<table_name_here>');
```

Comment: Referring to your latest answer, do you know how I can get the actual SQL behind the table? Not just the DDL, i would need the actual DML behind the table. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: @JustineMit If your table was createad using `CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT` you will find SELECT in query history.